# Extracting information from excel in r-markdown

Tags: r-markdown

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Liz3d.png)

I have the above data and in R I should do a regression model with Y=CC.q, X.1=VKM.q and X.2=Age.  However the question says "This time around, we are only interested in the VPAS vehicles.".

How can I extract only the VPAS dsts to construct my model? Thanks

Comment: Hi Rick! Welcome to StackOverflow. People generally prefer you to include your data and code in the question. Here is more info on how this can be done: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.